# Lock orientation with cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I'm using the plugin in my Ionic2 application:

```
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 2.0.1 "Screen Orientation"
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) {
    screenOrientation.lock(screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
  }
}
```

#### package.json

```
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-http": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
```

Why the application not working ? error:

```
NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported
```

Comment: Do you need to change the orientation during the lifecycle of your app? Or do you want to keep the same orientation for the whole application? If the latter, you may skip the plugin and directly put in your config.xml `<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />`

Comment: I do need it for the entire app - but that didn't work, this is why I was trying the plugin ( which also seems to not work :/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import [`Platform`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/) from `ionic-native` and wrap your `ScreenOrientation` calls in a `Platform.ready()` call. The `ready` function returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that resolves when the platform is ready and native functionality can be called. The reason its not working for you now is probably because the platform is not ready when the function is called.

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';

export class MyApp {
    constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation, private platform: Platform) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.screenOrientation.lock(screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The error no longer appears, but the orientation not working :/ but that's a different story ...

Comment: Check the edit, see if it resolves the issue. Does the orientation not get locked at all? Or does it get locked to the two different landscape-orientations?

Comment: strange, when I rotate emulator - it's locked, but when rotating a real device - it flips